# How can I create a Power BI Stacked Bar Chart that shows the overlap of Categories?

Tags: powerbi, dax, bar-chart, overlapping-matches

I have a table that looks something like this (but with several more columns I want to be able to filter by):

| Record ID | Record Name | Record Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Type1 | Inactive |
| 2 | A | Type1 | Active |
| 3 | A | Type2 | Inactive |
| 4 | B | Type2 | Active |
| 5 | B | Type1 | Active |
| 6 | C | Type1 | Inactive |
| 7 | D | Type1 | Active |

Essentially, I want to create a bar chart that shows the number of records for each record type as well as stack the bars to show any overlap by record name. For example, There are 5 records in Type 1, out of those that are in Type 1, two records are also in Type 2 (A & B). I need to be able to filter the chart by Status and other metrics (such as registration date). If there is a better way to visualize this I am open to suggestions since I have spent the past couple of days trying to figure out how this should work.

I tried creating count and filter measures in power BI and altering my SQL code when I pull from Oracle to get a kind of matrix table, but altering the SQL made the data unable to be filtered and I wasn't able to figure out how to get the measures to work the way I would need them to in order to get the desired result.

Comment: Why not use a Venn Diagram for that?
The Ultimate Venn Diagram custom visual may do exactly what you want.